# Why valarray does not have a swap function like vector in C++03?

Tags: c++

As title, I am confused about this. `swap` should be extremely useful if we are facing an iterative problem. The old vector and the new vector can be swapped by exchanging pointer-to-memory instead of contents. However, this is valid in `std::vector` but not in `std::valarray`. I am wondering why. In C++0x it seems the function is added, but why not in C++03?

Comment: Someone in a very bad mood voted this down, voted to close this, and moved along. LOL. Compensating +1 from me

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan and +1 one from me also, this is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: What's valid about this question? Unless you were on the standards committee when they debated `valarray`, there is _no_ possible way to answer it. These "why" questions are useless. The standard is what it is; there is no why.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but this really isn't a good question. Does anybody have an answer? This is a discussion... there are going to be opinions, not facts, used here.

Comment: Sometimes there are useful answers to why questions, just not when the answer happens to be "because the standardization comittee forgot."

Comment: Ditto what @Patrick87 said (except that I *am* the downvoter/closevoter...)

Comment: @Dennis: even then, the question is valid. There is *usually* a reason behind anything in C++, so you can't really fault people for wondering what the reason is in this case. It's a fair question.

Comment: @jalf: Yes that was my point. I was going to compare it to `basic_string::begin` invalidating iterators. Why that happens has a "real" answer beyond "the committee overlooked something"; maybe this does as well? Can't know unless you ask, so even if the answer happens to be uninspired, the question is useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because it doesn't.

I doubt there is a much better answer than that.  Omissions and mistakes happen (see also `std::vector::resize` taking its second argument by value, the missing `std::copy_if` algorithm, and [the very long list of closed Standard Library defects](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-closed.html)).

It's a good thing that the language continues to evolve and that mistakes like this can be rectified in future revisions of the language specification (like C++0x).

Comment: BTW: C++0x will correct the oversight and include a std::swap for them.

Comment: Right:  the OP states that in the last sentence of his question.  C++0x has many changes with respect to `swap`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you didn't suggest it to the language committee.

As soon as you build your time machine, and deliver your request sufficiently far in advance of the standard's publication date for it to be included, C++03 will have it as well.

Comment: "will have"? I think you need to review DNA's book on verb tenses for time travellers... :)

Comment: Ah, he didn't actually write such a book; it's merely described somewhere in the HHGTTG trilogy, and I forgot the exact context :(